# Using object fields in view

Tags: python, django

I have the following view function:

```
def DetailView(request, category_id):
try:
    items = Photos.objects.filter(name=category_id)
    context = {'items': items}
except Photos.DoesNotExist:
    raise Http404("Category unavailable")
return render(request, 'urcle/details.html', context)
```

So in 'items' there is a field userID
I would like to do the following:

```
users = Users.objects.filter(id=userID)
```

How can I get the userID from items (there is only one item in 'items')
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [the documentation says](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-a-single-object-with-get), `filter` always returns a queryset. If there's only one item, you should use `get` which returns an instance directly.

Comment: What do you mean? You access it like any other attribute.